# jersey api - how to login to webservice using redirect and cookies?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, cookies, jersey

Before I can use my web services, I have to login.  The login consists of a post with three parameters -- 'login', 'password', and 'redirectto'.  The server hands me a cookie and sends me a 302 redirect, sending me to the site specified in the 'redirectto' parameter. I'm not sure how to accept the cookie and use it on the redirect.  Here is my login code:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target("http://example.com/login.php?Login");

Form form = new Form();
form.param("login", "sam");
form.param("password", "password");
form.param("redirectto", "http://example.com/newLogin");

Response response = 
target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .post(Entity.entity(form,MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED));

System.out.println(response.getStatus());
System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this on the following blog site:
http://kingsfleet.blogspot.com/2015/02/per-client-cookie-handling-with-jersey.html

I used the JAX-WS 2.0 method listed in the blog.  You may have to view the page source to view the source code that is cut off on the blog.